# Нужно нарисовать произвольную фигуру с помощью canvas или SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, graphics

Вот скрин того, что должно получится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно рисовать произвольную форму (линия вокруг аватара темно-фиолетового цвета).

Все данные, что есть:
1) ширина и высота всего блока - 180x180 px;
2) ширина и высота аватара - 84x84px;
3) с backend приходят проценты - насколько пользователь близок к той или иной стихии. Например, земля - 30%, огонь - 60%, воздух - 44%, вода - 9%.

Исходя из этого и нужно построить график. При этом его линии никогда не должны быть под аватаром.

Я понимаю что это можно сделать с помощью canvas или svg, но как именно не знаю.

Может нужны еще какие-то пояснения, пишите.

The code:

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  background-color: #D49387;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ad589b), to(#facc76));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ad589b, #facc76);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ad589b, #facc76);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ad589b, #facc76);
}
.avatar {
  padding: 20px 0 40px;
}
.avatar__inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}
.avatar__image {
  margin-top: -42px;
  margin-left: -42px;
  border: 3px solid #facc76;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
          border-radius: 100%;
  width: 84px;
  height: 84px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.avatar__image:before {
  content: "";
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
          border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left bottom, from(rgba(173, 88, 155, 0.2)), to(rgba(250, 204, 118, 0.2)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, rgba(173, 88, 155, 0.2) 0%, rgba(250, 204, 118, 0.2) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top right, rgba(173, 88, 155, 0.2) 0%, rgba(250, 204, 118, 0.2) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(173, 88, 155, 0.2) 0%, rgba(250, 204, 118, 0.2) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.avatar__circles, .avatar__circles:before, .avatar__circles:after {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
          border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.avatar__circles:before, .avatar__circles:after {
  content: "";
}
.avatar__circles--1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.avatar__circles--1:before {
  margin-top: -82px;
  margin-left: -82px;
  width: 164px;
  height: 164px;
}
.avatar__circles--1:after {
  margin-top: -74px;
  margin-left: -74px;
  width: 148px;
  height: 148px;
}
.avatar__circles--2 {
  margin-top: -66px;
  margin-left: -66px;
  width: 132px;
  height: 132px;
}
.avatar__circles--2:before {
  margin-top: -58px;
  margin-left: -58px;
  width: 116px;
  height: 116px;
}
.avatar__circles--2:after {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.avatar__element {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
}
.avatar__element--position_top {
  margin-left: -17px;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
}
.avatar__element--position_right {
  margin-top: -17px;
  top: 50%;
  right: -30px;
}
.avatar__element--position_bottom {
  margin-left: -17px;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 50%;
}
.avatar__element--position_left {
  margin-top: -17px;
  top: 50%;
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="avatar__inner">
    <div class="avatar__image bg-image" style="background-image: url('./tmp_images/avatar.jpg');"></div>
    <span class="avatar__circles avatar__circles--1"></span>
    <span class="avatar__circles avatar__circles--2"></span>
    <span class="avatar__element avatar__element--position_top">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 99 99">
        <circle fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#F9C778" cx="49.5" cy="49.5" r="49.5"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M77.5,46.8c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.4-1.8c-0.3-1.3-0.5-2.7-1-4c-3.9-11-11.7-17.5-23.2-19.3
                                c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l-5.3,0l-0.1,0c-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.2-1.4,0.3c-1,0.2-2,0.4-2.9,0.6
                                c-11.2,2.8-19.6,12.4-20.9,24c-1.6,15.2,8.8,28.8,23.8,31c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1,0.2l0.5,0.1l5.1,0l0.1,0c0.4-0.1,0.8-0.2,1.2-0.2
                                c0.9-0.2,1.8-0.3,2.7-0.6c11.6-2.9,19.7-12.1,21.2-24c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2l0-0.1v-5.3L77.5,46.8z
                                M44.7,69.1c-0.2-1.1-0.7-2-1.1-3c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.5-1.1c-0.5-1-0.4-2.3,0.3-3.3c0.7-1.1,1.9-1.7,3.3-1.6
                                c0.2,0,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.4c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.5c0.8,0.6,1.5,1.2,2.1,1.9c2.3,2.6,5.4,4.3,9.7,5.4c1.4,0.3,2.8,0.7,4.2,1l0.6,0.1
                                c-3,2.8-9.9,5.1-15.7,5.1c-1.6,0-3-0.2-4.1-0.6c0-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.1C44.8,71.7,44.9,70.4,44.7,69.1z M53.4,62
                                c-0.9-0.8-1.8-1.6-2.7-2.4c-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.4-1.3c-1.4-1.3-3.2-1.6-4.9-0.8c-1.5,0.7-2.7,1.5-3.6,2.4c-1.6,1.7-1.9,3.7-0.9,5.8
                                c0.5,1,0.9,1.9,1.4,2.9c0.7,1.4,0.8,3,0.4,4.7c-4.6-0.6-12.8-7.6-14.6-12.4c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4-0.1c0.9-0.1,1.8-0.3,2.7-0.5
                                c1.6-0.4,2.9-0.9,4.1-1.4c1.6-0.7,1.8-1.8,1.6-3.2l-0.1-0.3c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.2-1.3c-0.1-1.4,0.4-1.9,1.8-2.1
                                c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1-0.1c0.7,0,1.4,0,2.2-0.2c1.1-0.3,2.1-1,2.8-1.7c1.3-1.5,2.5-3.2,3.6-4.8l0.3-0.4c1.1-1.6,1-3.6-0.2-4.9
                                c-1.8-1.8-3.7-3.3-5.4-4.6c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.9-0.3c-0.5,0-1,0.1-1.4,0.4c-0.8,0.5-1.4,1.1-2.1,1.8c-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.4h0
                                c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1c-2.3-0.6-4.5-1.5-6.9-3.1c3.4-4.5,7.7-7.6,13-9.2c2.7-0.8,5.5-1.2,8.5-1c0.3,0,0.4,0.1,0.4,0.1
                                c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.3c-0.1,2.5,0.7,4.8,2.4,6.8c0.9,1,1.8,2,2.6,2.9l0.3,0.4c1.1,1.1,2.5,1.6,4.1,1.5c0.3,0,0.6,0,1-0.1
                                c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1-0.1c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.3,0c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.3c-0.4,1.3-0.9,2.4-1.5,3.4
                                c-1.3,1.9-1.7,3.9-1.1,6c0.5,2.2,1.1,4.2,1.9,6.2c0.6,1.7,2,2.6,4,2.6l0.2,0c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.7-0.1c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.9-0.1
                                c1.5,0,3,1.3,3.3,2.7c0,0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.7c-1.1,2.7-2.7,5.1-4.7,7.2c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3c-4.2-0.5-7.8-1.5-11.2-3
                                c-0.7-0.3-1.3-0.8-1.9-1.4C53.8,62.3,53.6,62.1,53.4,62z M34.8,40.5c2.2,0.7,3.9,0.2,5.1-1.3c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.7
                                c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.8C42.9,40,44,41,45,42c0.4,0.4,0.3,0.9,0,1.4c-0.4,0.5-0.8,1.1-1.2,1.6
                                c-0.8,1.1-1.6,2.2-2.5,3.2c-0.3,0.4-1,0.6-1.6,0.8l-0.3,0.1c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0-0.8,0c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0c-1.9,0-3.4,0.6-4.3,1.7
                                c-0.9,1.1-1.2,2.7-0.9,4.5c0.1,0.5,0.2,1,0.1,1.1c-0.1,0.1-0.7,0.3-1,0.4c-1.4,0.4-2.9,0.7-4.4,1L26.3,58c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0
                                c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3-0.3c-2.3-7.1-1.7-13.9,1.8-20.5l1.2,0.6c1.4,0.7,2.8,1.4,4.2,2c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.3,1.4,0.5L34.8,40.5z M67.8,53
                                c-0.8,0.1-1.4,0.2-1.9,0.2c-1.3,0-1.5-0.3-2.5-3.2c-0.4-1.3-0.7-2.7-0.8-4.2c0-0.7,0.2-1.5,0.6-2.2c1.2-2.2,2.4-4.5,2.8-7.2
                                c0.1-1,0-1.7-0.4-2.2c-0.5-0.6-1.4-0.8-2-0.9c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0c-0.5,0-1,0.1-1.4,0c-0.9-0.1-1.5-0.3-1.8-0.6
                                c-1.3-1.3-2.5-2.7-3.8-4.4c-0.6-0.8-0.9-1.9-0.8-3.3c6.4,0.9,12.3,4.7,16.1,10.6c3.9,5.9,5.2,12.9,3.6,19.3c-1.3-1.3-2.9-2-4.9-2
                                C68.6,52.9,68.2,52.9,67.8,53z"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M51.5,50.3l-0.1,0c-1.9,0-3.3,1.4-3.4,3.3c0,1.8,1.4,3.4,3.1,3.5l0.1,0c1.7,0,3.4-1.7,3.4-3.5
                                C54.6,51.7,53.3,50.4,51.5,50.3z M51.5,53.5c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.3c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1
                                C51.2,53.6,51.3,53.5,51.5,53.5z M51.2,56.5C51.2,56.5,51.2,56.5,51.2,56.5L51.2,56.5L51.2,56.5z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="avatar__element avatar__element--active avatar__element--position_right">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 99 99">
        <circle fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#F9C778" cx="49.5" cy="49.5" r="49.5"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M74.3,50c-1-5.2-2.8-10.2-5.7-14.8c-1.3-2-3-3.6-4.7-5.5c0.2,1.6,0.4,3,0.5,4.4c0.2,2.1,0.2,4.3-0.6,6.3
                                                                        c-0.8,2-2.3,3-4,2.9c-1.4-0.1-2.6-0.9-3.4-2c-1.5-1.9-1.9-4.1-1.6-6.4c0.2-1.6,0.6-3.1,0.9-4.7c0.3-1.8,0.6-3.7,0.3-5.6
                                                                        c-0.7-3.5-4.3-7.1-8.1-7.9c0.2,1.1,0.5,2.2,0.7,3.3c0.6,2.8-0.1,5.1-2.7,6.8c-0.8,0.5-1.6,1.1-2.4,1.7c-4.1,3-6.3,7.1-6.1,12.2
                                                                        c0.1,1.6,0.4,3.1,0.6,4.7c0.3,2,0.1,3.9-1.5,5.3c-0.8,0.7-1.6,0.8-2.4,0.2c-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.6-1-0.9c-1.5-2-2-4.4-1.8-6.8
                                                                        c0.1-1.7,0.4-3.4,0.6-5.3c-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.9-1,1.3c-1.8,2.4-3.7,4.7-4.9,7.6c-2,5.1-2.1,10.4-0.8,15.7c1.5,6,4.5,11.2,9.4,15
                                                                        c5.4,4.2,11.6,5.6,18.3,4.8c7-0.8,12.7-4.1,16.8-9.8C74.2,65.6,75.9,58.1,74.3,50z M72.3,56.1c-0.3,8.5-3.7,15.6-11,20.4
                                                                        c-4.1,2.7-8.8,3.5-13.7,3.2c-5.8-0.4-10.7-2.8-14.5-7.1c-3.4-3.8-5.4-8.3-6.1-13.4c-0.6-3.9-0.3-7.8,1.2-11.6
                                                                        c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.4-1c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c0.2,0.7,0.3,1.3,0.6,1.9c0.6,1.7,1.5,3.3,2.9,4.4c1.8,1.4,4,1.3,5.8-0.2
                                                                        c2.2-1.9,2.8-4.3,2.4-7.1c-0.3-1.7-0.6-3.4-0.6-5.1c-0.1-4,1.6-7.2,4.8-9.6c1.1-0.9,2.3-1.6,3.5-2.4c2.1-1.5,3.3-3.5,3.2-6.1
                                                                        c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4c1.2,1.2,1.8,2.5,2,4.1c0.2,2.2-0.3,4.3-0.8,6.4c-0.6,3-0.7,5.9,0.7,8.8c1.3,2.6,3.2,4.4,6.3,4.8
                                                                        c2.2,0.3,4-0.6,5.4-2.3c1.3-1.5,1.8-3.4,2.1-5.3c0-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.5c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.8,1.7,1.6,3.4,2.3,5.1
                                                                        C71.2,47,72.5,51.5,72.3,56.1z"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M61.2,56c-1.9-2.3-4-4.4-5.9-6.7c-1.3-1.5-2.6-3.1-3.7-4.8c-1.5-2.4-2.2-5.1-2.1-7.9c0-0.9,0-1.7,0-2.8
                                                                        c-1.1,1-2.1,1.9-3,2.8c-3.1,3.1-4.1,6.9-2.9,11.1c0.7,2.5,1.9,4.9,2.8,7.4c0.6,1.5,1.2,3,1.6,4.6c0.6,2.7-1.4,4.8-4,4.4
                                                                        c-1.1-0.2-2.1-0.6-3-1.1c-1.7-1-2.7-2.7-3.4-4.5c-0.4-1-0.7-2.1-1.1-3.2c-0.5,1.1-1.1,2.2-1.5,3.2c-2.7,6.2-0.9,12.7,4.7,16.5
                                                                        c4.3,2.9,9.1,3.6,14.1,2.5c4.5-1,8-3.5,10.1-7.7c1.3-2.6,1.5-5.2,0.5-8C63.6,59.6,62.6,57.7,61.2,56z M61.5,68.6
                                                                        c-1.8,3.5-4.7,5.5-8.5,6.3c-4.5,0.9-8.7,0.3-12.4-2.5c-3.4-2.6-4.8-6-4.2-10.5c0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9c2,2.5,4.5,3.9,7.8,3.7
                                                                        c3.6-0.2,6.2-3.5,5.6-7.1c-0.4-2.5-1.5-4.7-2.5-6.9c-1-2.3-2-4.5-2.3-7c-0.2-2.1,0.1-4,1.3-5.8c0.3,1.1,0.6,2.2,1,3.3
                                                                        c1.1,3.1,3.2,5.5,5.3,7.9c2,2.2,4.1,4.3,5.9,6.7c1.1,1.4,1.8,3.1,2.5,4.7C62.8,64.5,62.5,66.6,61.5,68.6z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="avatar__element avatar__element--position_bottom">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 99 99">
        <circle fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#F9C778" cx="49.5" cy="49.5" r="49.5"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M73.9,36.5c-2.7-0.6-5,0.1-6.8,2c-2.1,2.2-2.1,5.9-0.1,7.9c0.7,0.7,1.7,0.7,2.4,0.1c0.8-0.6,0.9-1.6,0.3-2.5
                                c-0.5-0.8-0.7-1.6-0.4-2.3c0.2-0.7,0.8-1.3,1.7-1.6c1.4-0.5,2.7-0.2,3.8,0.7c1.1,1,1.5,2.4,1.2,3.9c-0.5,2.1-2.6,3.6-5,3.6l-4.6,0
                                l-13.7,0c-6.2,0-12.3,0-18.5,0c-0.9,0-1.5,0.4-1.8,1.1c-0.2,0.6-0.2,1.2,0.2,1.6c0.4,0.5,1,0.8,1.8,0.8c2.9,0,5.9,0,8.8,0l9.6,0
                                l8.8,0c3,0,6.1,0,9.1,0c0.9,0,1.7-0.1,2.5-0.3c2.3-0.5,4.3-2,5.5-3.9c1.1-1.9,1.4-4.1,0.8-6.1C78.6,38.9,76.7,37.2,73.9,36.5z"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M58.7,57.7c-1.9,0-3.9-0.1-6.3-0.1c-1.6,0-3.2,0-4.9,0c-1.6,0-3.3,0-4.9,0h-0.5v0l-6.7,0c-2.8,0-5.6,0-8.5,0
                                c-0.6,0-1.1,0.1-1.5,0.4c-0.7,0.4-0.8,1.2-0.6,1.9c0.2,0.8,0.9,1.3,1.8,1.3c0.8,0,1.6,0,2.3,0l28.6,0c1.9,0,3.4,0.6,4.4,1.9
                                c1,1.2,1.2,2.6,0.7,4c-0.5,1.3-1.5,2.1-2.9,2.3c-1.1,0.2-2.2-0.3-2.8-1.1c-0.4-0.5-0.5-1.2-0.4-1.8c0.1-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.6
                                c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.7-1.2-0.8c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0c-0.9,0-1.6,0.7-1.8,1.8c-0.4,2.5,0.4,4.5,2.5,5.9c2.2,1.5,4.6,1.6,7.1,0.4
                                c2.5-1.3,3.8-3.4,4-6.2c0.1-2-0.7-4.1-2.2-5.7C62.9,58.7,60.8,57.8,58.7,57.7z"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M41.1,42.8c1.9,0,3.9,0,5.8,0c1,0,2-0.2,2.9-0.4c4.3-1.3,6.9-5.3,6.2-9.6c-0.6-3.8-4.1-6.8-8-6.8
                                c-0.5,0-1.1,0.1-1.6,0.2c-3.2,0.7-5.2,2.6-5.9,5.6c-0.2,0.7-0.2,1.5-0.1,2.4c0.1,0.9,0.9,1.5,1.9,1.3c0.9-0.1,1.6-0.8,1.5-1.8
                                c0-1.4,0.4-2.5,1.4-3.3c1.4-1,3.5-1.1,5-0.1c1.6,1,2.4,2.9,2,4.7c-0.6,2.5-2.8,4.2-5.4,4.2l-10.2,0c-5.1,0-10.2,0-15.4,0
                                c-0.4,0-0.9,0.1-1.2,0.2c-0.7,0.3-1.1,1.1-0.9,2c0.2,0.8,0.9,1.4,1.9,1.4c2.1,0,4.1,0,6.2,0l6.9,0L41.1,42.8z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="avatar__element avatar__element--position_left">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 99 99">
        <circle fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#F9C778" cx="49.5" cy="49.5" r="49.5"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M65.4,50.9c-1.4-2.5-3.1-4.8-4.8-7.1c-0.4-0.6-0.9-1.2-1.3-1.9l-0.3-0.4C57,38.8,55,36,53.4,32.9
                                c-0.8-1.5-1.8-3.6-2.2-5.9c-0.2-1.2-0.3-2.3-0.4-3.5c0-0.4-0.1-0.9-0.1-1.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2c-2.9,2.8-5.1,5.2-6.9,7.5
                                c-2,2.7-3.8,5.5-5.3,8.2c-2.2,3.9-4,7.5-5.3,11.1c-0.9,2.4-1.5,4.5-1.9,6.7c-0.5,2.6-0.4,5.2,0.3,7.8c1,3.7,3,6.9,6,9.4
                                c2.6,2.2,5.6,3.5,8.8,4c0.4,0.1,0.9,0.1,1.3,0.2l0.5,0.1h2c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c2.4-0.2,4.6-0.8,6.7-1.8c2.5-1.2,4.7-3,6.5-5.2
                                c1.2-1.5,2.1-3.1,2.7-4.9c0.8-2.1,1.2-4.4,1.1-6.6C67.8,55.6,66.6,53.1,65.4,50.9z M64.5,61.7c-0.5,2.7-1.7,5-3.5,7.1
                                c-2.7,3-5.9,4.7-9.8,5.1c-0.6,0.1-1.2,0.1-1.8,0.1l0,0c-3.4,0-6.5-1.1-9.2-3.1c-2.5-1.9-4.3-4.4-5.3-7.5c-0.8-2.5-0.9-5.2-0.4-8
                                c1-4.5,2.8-8.5,4.2-11.5c1.9-3.8,4-7.4,6.4-10.9c0.4-0.6,0.9-1.2,1.3-1.8l0.4-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3l1.2-1.4l0.8,2
                                c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.8c1.1,2.7,2.6,5.3,4.7,8.4c1.1,1.6,2.2,3.1,3.3,4.7c1.1,1.5,2.2,3.1,3.3,4.6c1.5,2.2,2.6,4.2,3.4,6.2
                                C64.9,57.3,65,59.3,64.5,61.7z"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M42.5,61.3c-1.2-2.8-1.1-5.7-0.9-8.6c0.1-1.2,0.3-2.4,0.4-3.7c-2.2,2.3-3.4,5-3.6,8.2
                                c-0.2,3.1,0.8,5.8,2.7,8.1c1.6,1.9,3.6,3.3,6.2,3.7c0.8,0.1,1.6,0.2,2.5,0c-0.5-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.2-0.7
                                C45.8,66.7,43.8,64.3,42.5,61.3z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А все остальное вы уже реализовали? Отрисовка аватара, кругов, значков? Вам только линию вокруг аватара осталось нарисовать?

Comment: Да, остальное есть это просто верстка

Comment: Тогда добавьте код в вопрос, что бы было понятно, как делать.

Comment: Добавил HTML и CSS код

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Кривые_Безье - в двух словах - желательно в ai открыть центрированную версию этоой фигуры, найти в ней нужные точки и их двигать. Но можно фигуру и по точкам нарисовать

Comment: Спасибо. Но вот мне как раз нужно рисовать динамически фигуру исходя из процентов